# Python - Writing data to a data frame is rewriting the empty sets from the next available location

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a large text file of almost 600 properties. I am trying to convert these into a csv file. So, I loaded the text file and created a data frame and loaded them into a csv file. Below is the list of my data which has 2 properties( I do have missing values in my property set - here price per quarter is missing in the 2nd set),

```
Name of the Property : North Kensington Upcycling Store and Cafe
Availability : Now 
Area :  1,200 sqft
Retail Type  : No
Bar & Restaurant Type  : No
Event Type  : Yes
Shop Share Type  : No
Unique Type  : No
Price Per Day : £360
Price Per Week : £1,260
Price Per Month : £5,460
Price Per Quarter : £16,380
Price Per Year : £65,520
[Latitude, Longitude] : [51.5235108631773, -0.206594467163086]
Name of the Property : Old Charlton Pub
Availability : Now 
Area :  1,250 sqft
Retail Type  : No
Bar & Restaurant Type  : Yes
Event Type  : No
Shop Share Type  : No
Unique Type  : No
Price Per Day : £70
Price Per Week : £490
Price Per Month : £2,129
Price Per Year : £25,550
[Latitude, Longitude] : [51.4926332979245, 0.0449645519256592]
```

This is the code that I wrote -

```
import pandas
import csv

txt_file = r"sa4.txt"
txt = open(txt_file, "r")
txt_string = txt.read()
txt_lines = txt_string.split("\n")
txt_dict = {}

for txt_line in txt_lines:
    k,v = txt_line.split(":")
    k = k.strip()
    v = v.strip()
    if k in txt_dict:
        list = txt_dict.get(k)
    else:
        list = []
    list.append(v)
    txt_dict[k]=list
print(df)
df.to_csv("MYFILE2.csv")
```

and this is my output csv file - [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y1Cs.png) I don't know **why that value in Price per Quarter for the 2nd property came from the 5th property price per quarter [ which is the next available location ]? IT has to be NULL, but it has become £135000** . Can anyone see the problem in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried pandas's [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?

Comment: No..I haven't. As I am not peculiar with it. The problem is when I print my data frame which is the df. I am still seeing the same problem. I feel, I have missed out somewhere inside the loop. @Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply because your list does not have a placeholder for Price per Quarter when it goes missing. To solve it, you will have to keep track of the property record number. Something like this should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

txt_file = r"sa4.txt"
txt = open(txt_file, "r")
txt_string = txt.read()
txt_lines = txt_string.split("\n")
df = pd.DataFrame()
idx = -1 # This will make sense in the `if` block below

for txt_line in txt_lines:
    k,v = txt_line.split(":")
    k = k.strip()
    v = v.strip()
    if k == 'Name of the Property':
        idx += 1 # Now, idx will be 0 for the first run
    df.loc[idx, k] = v
print(df)
df.to_csv("MYFILE2.csv")
```

Comment: Thats perfect ! Thanks a lot